# Argument must extend class

Tags: typescript

I'm moving to Typescript for a variety of reasons, and so far I'm supremely happy with it.

One of the issues that I've ran into is verifying that an argument passed to a function extends another class.

For instance:

```
class Foo {
    public $xyz
}

class Bar {
    constructor(model: extends Foo)
}

class Baz extends Foo {}
```

Many classes can extend foo, besides Baz, but they all have the same properties. I need to ensure that the class being passed to the `model` argument of the constructor `Bar` correctly extends `Foo`.

How can I achieve this?

(please forgive the terrible psuedo-code above)

If my approach is wrong, I'd love to hear what I could do to solve that problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
constructor(model: Foo)
```

Is what you are looking for. This states that the passed instance `model` is of type `Foo` or inherits from `Foo`.

The keyword `extends` can only be used in type declarations to denote that the type extends (inherits from) another type.

See also [Classes documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html).

Comment: Really?! So even if the model is `Baz` that's being passed to the argument, it extends `Foo` or implements `Foo` and therefore passes it?

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I was thinking that wasn't the way to go. Appreciate it